# iOS:How to separate particular string element in array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, string

I got following response from server:

```
[{"bp":"000/000","dateTime":"05/12/2016 01:02:59 PM","doc":{"email_id":"batra@gmail.com","exception":0,"gender":"Male","id":0,"mobile_no":8055621745,"name":"Batra","profile_id":0,"qualification":"MD(Doctor)","reg_id":157,"salutation":"Mr","wellness_id":"251215782521"},"follow_up":"17","id":37,"medicine":["Syrup,Decold Total,20,0-0-1,Before Meal,1","Injection,Insulin,1,0-0-1,Before Meal,1","no","no","no","no","no","no","no","no"],"patient":{"email_id":"bishtrohit1989@gmail.com","exception":0,"gender":"Male","id":0,"mobile_no":8055621745,"name":"Rohit","profile_id":0,"qualification":"","reg_id":150,"salutation":"Mr","wellness_id":"290119935030"},"weight":"000"}]
```

From that I have separate the `medicine` array like following way:

```
NSMutableArray *Myarray = [NSMutableArray new];
for (int i=0; i<_menuItems.count; i++) {
    [Myarray addObject:[[_menuItems objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"medicine"]];
    NSLog(@"medicine: %@",Myarray);
```

I got output for this as like:

```
medicine: (
        (
        "Syrup,Decold Total,20,0-0-1,Before Meal,1",
        "Injection,Insulin,1,0-0-1,Before Meal,1",
        no,
        no,
        no,
        no,
        no,
        no,
        no,
        no
    )
)
```

**Now what i want:**

1) remove that all `no`element.

2) after that, i want only 2nd element in each string.

in short i want my final output is like:

`[Decold Total, Insulin];`

But i don't know how to do that..??

Please anyone can solve my issue. help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `NSPredicate` on `Myarray` and filter it.

Make your `Myarray` like this.
NSMutableArray *Myarray = [NSMutableArray new];

```
for (int i=0; i<_menuItems.count; i++) {
     [Myarray addObjectsFromArray:[[_menuItems objectAtIndex:i] objectForKey:@"medicine"]];
}
```

1) Remove that all `no` element.

```
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"NOT (SELF = %@)",@"no"];
NSArray *filterArray = [Myarray filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
```

2) Want only 2nd element in each string

```
NSMutableArray *medicineArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString* medicine in filterArray) {
     NSArray *arr = [medicine componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
     if (arr.count >= 2)  {
          [medicineArray addObject:[arr objectAtIndex:1]];
     }
}
```

Comment: filter:  (
        (
        "Syrup,Decold Total,20,0-0-1,Before Meal,1",
        "Injection,Insulin,1,0-0-1,Before Meal,1",
        no,
        no,
        no,
        no,
        no,
        no,
        no,
        no
    )
)    This is outpot..

Comment: when i do like :             if (Myarray.count>0) {
                
                NSLog(@"count: %u",Myarray.count);}
it print count: 1

Comment: i just want my final output like [Decold Total, Insulin];.. what should i do for that..

Comment: @SurajSukale Check the edited answer and add object in your `Myarray` like i have done in for loop.

Comment: @SurajSukale Welcome mate :)